# Retrieve dropdownlist by index?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 3 items in my dropdownlist (it will always be different and the number of items may be less but not more, bounded by a sqldatasource) and 3 chart controls.  The idea is that each of those items in the dropdownlist will run some query and be bounded to their own individual charts on pageload.  I was thinking of maybe retrieving the ddl by its index, but i'm not sure how or even that is the right approach.

I was thinking of something like this or will a foreach loop work?:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (DropDownList1.Items == DropDownList1[0]);
    {
        DataTable dt = this.test();
        Chart0.DataSource = dt;
        Chart0.DataBind();
    }

    if (DropDownList1.Items == DropDownList1[1]) ;
    {
        DataTable dt1 = this.test1();
        Chart1.DataSource = dt1;
        Chart1.DataBind();
    }

    else if (DropDownList1.Items == DropDownList1[2]) ;
    {
        DataTable dt2 = this.test2();
        Chart2.DataSource = dt2;
        Chart2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.  I can use DropDownList1.Items[INDEX].Text as a parameter value.